# application is killed by the system if unmount SD Card in time of writing to file

Tags: android

I write to file by the next way:

```
        long byteCount = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = zipStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            fOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            byteCount += bytesRead;
```

//...

```
         if (fOut != null) {
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        }
        if (zipStream != null) {
            zipStream.close();
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {...}
```

When I unount my SD Card in time of downloading the System always kills my application process in several seconds. As I understand it occurs because the System needs to clear the resources that are still alive after SD Card unmounting. How to avoid killing my application in this case?

Everything that I catch:

```
 W/System.err(2732): java.io.IOException: I/O error
06-06 16:25:01.411: W/System.err(2732):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.write(Native Method)
06-06 16:25:01.411: W/System.err(2732):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:171)
06-06 16:25:01.411: W/System.err(2732):
```

Comment: Are you catching any Exceptions?

Comment: Yes, I catch all exceptions.

Comment: This is expected behavior, please see the Android docs.

Comment: I know that it's expected behavior, but maybe there are some ways to get rid of this (to make it another way)?

Comment: Is your app installed on sd-card or using external cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to media state changes and finish the activity or stop the writing process(es) when SD card is unmounted.

Following should get your started:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mStorageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED ||
            action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL ||
            action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT ||
            action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_NOFS ||
            action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED ||
            action == Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED) {
            finish();
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_NOFS);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    registerReceiver(mStorageReceiver, filter);
}
```

Please check [Intent API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for additional media related actions. Also, do not forget to unregister `mStorageReceiver` when you are done with the activity/process.